# Binding query to datagrid with WPF and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, linq, datagrid

Ok, so what I have is a datagrid in wpf that I want to bind to the results of a linq query using the entity framework. For instance, lets say I have a list of products and I want to display only products on sale:

```
var itemsOnSale = from item in context.products 
       where item.onSale == true 
       select item;
context.products.Load();
productViewSource.Source = itemsOnSale.ToList();
```

But here's the catch: I also want to be able to add/edit the products on sale directly in the datagridview and save the changes to the database. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are going to need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the properties of the entities.

Answer (score 3):

One of the best way to bound your query to your `DataGrid` is doing the following:

```
var itemsOnSale = from item in context.products 
       where item.onSale == true 
       select item;

itemsOnSale.Load();
productViewSource.Source=context.products.Local;
```

From this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/09/08/data-binding-with-dbcontext.aspx):

> `Load` is a new extension method on `IQueryable` that will cause the
>   results of the query to be iterated, in EF this equates to
>   materializing the results as objects and adding them to the `DbContext`
>   in the `Unchanged` state
>
> The `Local` property will give you an `ObservableCollection<TEntity>` that
>   contains all `Unchanged`, `Modified` and `Added` objects that are currently
>   tracked by the `DbContext` for the given `DbSet`. As new objects enter the
>   `DbSet` (through queries, `DbSet`.`Add`/`Attach`, etc.) they will appear in
>   the `ObservableCollection`. When an object is deleted from the DbSet it
>   will also be removed from the `ObservableCollection`. Adding or Removing
>   from the ObservableCollection will also perform the corresponding
>   `Add`/`Remove` on the `DbSet`. Because WPF natively supports binding to an
>   `ObservableCollection` there is no additional code required to have two
>   way data binding with full support for WPF sorting, filtering etc.

Now to save that changes on your `DataGrid`, the only you need to do is create a method or a [command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx) that call `SaveChanges` method of your context:

```
private void SaveProductChanges()
{
   context.SaveChanges(); 
}
```